# Will there be any delays if I apply for a Canadian passport, using a citizenship certificate that was issued when I was a child?

Tags: passports, canada

I am a dual citizen of the United States and Canada. I have never held a Canadian passport, and I decided to put together my application for one.

I have a Canadian citizenship certificate, and that is required to send in with the passport application. But this certificate card was issued when I was 2 years old. There's no expiration date on the card, but I wonder if my application will be scrutinized or otherwise delayed if I send in a card with a photo from over 25 years ago with a picture of a child on it - that kid could be anybody, after all!

I thought about first [updating my citizenship certificate](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/CIT0001ETOC.asp) but the processing time takes about 5 months.

Is it necessary or required to update the citizenship certificate, particularly in support of the passport application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fine. In fact, the Canadian certificates of citizenship that are issued currently are just a piece of paper with no photo at all (they stopped issuing the cards with a photo a few years back).

Answer (score 2):

I [emailed the passport program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/passport/contact.asp) and asked them, their response:

> The one you have should be accepted, don’t need to update.

along with some other general info as to what constitutes valid citizenship documentation.